# Will my Windows 8.1 app work on Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 8.1 app that was developed with the intent of being sideloaded on a tablet as a Line-of-Business application. The client decided to go for the specified tablets but with Windows 10 as an operating system. Will my app still work? This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-root#if-you-have-a-windows-8-1-app) seems to suggest that I need to do some kind of porting. I assume that I would also have to upgrade my Visual Studio to 2015 since I am currently on VS2013 and that cannot create Universal apps.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

TIA,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

> Will my app still work?

Apps built for Windows 8.1 run fine on Windows 10 devices, but to take advantage of the many *new features in the Windows 10 platform* or to *extend* your app to run on additional device families, you'll need to migrate them.

> This link seems to suggest that I need to do some kind of porting

That [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-root) just tell us it will be easy to port a Universal/Windows/WP 8.1 app to UWP:

> If you have a Universal 8.1 app—whether it's targeting Windows 8.1,
>   Windows Phone 8.1, or both—then you'll find that your source code and
>   skills will port smoothly to Windows 10.

Comment: Hi Franklin, the reason I asked this question is that my Windows 8.1 app runs ok on my Windows 8.1 development machine when ran in the Simulator, but once it gets sideloaded on the Windows 10 tablet it does not want to start. No errors are logged in the Event Viewer and I am really at a loss as to why is that happening.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this situation? What can be done to figure out where lies the problem?

Comment: @Eddie do you have any Win10 devices? You may set debug target to this device and start remote debug, may be you can catch Crash Dump or exception